# downgrade NPM version on mac

Tags: node.js, npm, version, downgrade

I'm trying to downgrade my NPM version from 6.5.0 -> 6.2.0 (i'm on MAC OS)

running `npm install -g npm@6.2.0`

however it still shows version 6.5.0 in the terminal with `npm -v` (also after reboot)

Something i'm missing here ? i want to be able to switch between versions with easy, preferably not by reinstalling Node and NPM each time.

Answer (score 3):

Best use `nvm`, the Node package manager. You can effortlessly switch between Node versions and their matching npm versions.

Try `which npm` and check your `.profile` and `.bashrc` files, maybe you have a specific npm path in there?

Comment: Here's a link to installtion instructions: [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installation-and-update)